# Prove that function is analytic.

Tags: complex-analysis

1. $f(z)$ is analytic function
2. $f(0)=0$

I want to prove that $\frac{f(z)}{z}$ is analytic function.

It is obvious that it is analytic everywhere except $0$ point. I found that $0$ is removable singularity, hope that might help.
I tried using z=x+iy and attempted to split f into a u(x,y)+iv(x,y) to apply the Cauchy Riemann equations, but this is proving to be very cumbersome. Is there a better way to prove this?

Comment: Where do you want it to be analytic? Because if you take the crown 0 < |z| < r for any r bigger tanh zero than its an open set where the function is defined in every point and has a Laurent series (arround 0) with every negative coeficient being zero (since f(0) =0 )

Comment: It is obvious that $f(z)/z$ is analytic at $0$ : by definition $f$ is given near $0$ by a power series whose constant term is $0$. Away from $0$ it is the product of two analytic functions $f(z),1/z$ thus it is analytic. The non-trivial theorem is that those conditions imply that $f(z)/z$ is given by a single power series convergent on the whole of $\Bbb{C}$.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, $\frac{f(z)}z$ is defined on $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$ only and there it is clearly an analytical function, since it is the quotient of two analytic functions.

If you consider the function$$\begin{array}{rccc}F\colon&\mathbb C&\longrightarrow&\mathbb C\\&z&\mapsto&\begin{cases}\frac{f(z)}z&\text{ if }z\neq0\\\lim_{z\to0}\frac{f(z)}z&\text{ if }z=0,\end{cases}\end{array}$$it is still analytic. It follows from the previous paragraph that $F|_{\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}}$ is analytic. And, since near $0$ you have$$f(z)=a_1z+a_2z^2+a_3z^3+\cdots,$$then$$F(z)=a_1+a_2z+a_3z^2+\cdots$$

Comment: I think you meant to write "It follows from the previous paragraph that $F|_{\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}}$ is analytic."

Comment: @Joe Indeed. I've edited my answer. Thank you.