# If $f(x)$ is analytic within some region, and has no zeroth order coefficient, is $f(x)/x$ also analytic?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

Let $f(z), z\in \mathbb{C}$ be have a convergent expansion for $|z|<\rho<\infty$, such that
$$f(z) = a_1z + a_2z^2 +\dots $$ (i.e. the constant order term is zero).
Is it true that $\frac{f(z)}{z}$ is analytic everywhere that $f(z)$ is analytic?

If convergence of $f(z)$ is proven by the ratio test $|b_{k+1}|/|b_k|<1$, where $b_k$ is the $k^{th}$ term in some series, then it is trivially true that the series for $\frac{f(z)}{z}$ converges iff $f(z)$'s series satisfies the ratio test, as we pulled the same factor out of all terms in the series. But it's not totally clear to me in the general case.

Comment: Related (duplicate?): https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3516356/42969

Comment: I'm not totally sure: I'm interested in whether the radius of convergence changes. The above links appear to be about entire functions. Could there be a difference?

Comment: The radius of convergence does not change as for $z\neq 0$  the series $\sum_{n=1} a_nz^n$ is convergent iff the series $\sum_{n=1} a_nz^{n-1}$ is convergent.

Comment: Fantastic, this is exactly what I needed. Is this obvious?

Comment: Think of $z$ (or $1/z$) as a constant. Since constant multiples commute with limits of sequences,...

Comment: What @RyszardSzwarc stated is true but I wouldn't say that it is obvious because it is equivalent to proving that $\text{limsup}_{n\to +\infty} |a_n|^{1/n} = \text{limsup}_{n\to +\infty} |a_n|^{1/(n+1)}$ and there is no change of variable that makes this trivial. One wasy way would be to assume this not to be true, then you have a strict inequality and you can use the characterization of the limit superior to conclude with a contradiction. It is worthwile to notice that by the same procedure one proves that the series differentiated term by term has at least the same radius as the original.

Comment: @MatteoMenghini It is obvious basing solely on the [definition](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radius_of_convergence) of the radius of convergence, not on the formula for this radius, which is a theorem.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc You are absolutely right on that.

Comment: @MatteoMenghini your comment is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you. If you want to submit that as an answer, I'll accept it.